# python tkinter - canvas - image

Tags: python, tkinter

I have 2 files one with the GUI and another with the background code. I am sending the file path to the image from my background code but I cannot show it successfully. see below the code:
the function img_update returns a string path to the image.

```
    self.Canvas1 = tk.Canvas(self.top)
    self.Canvas1.place(relx=0.646, rely=0.026, relheight=0.251
                    , relwidth=0.32)
    self.Canvas1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
    self.Canvas1.configure(borderwidth="2")
    self.Canvas1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
    self.Canvas1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
    self.Canvas1.configure(insertbackground="black")
    self.Canvas1.configure(relief="ridge")
    self.Canvas1.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
    self.Canvas1.configure(selectforeground="black")
    root.img = img = tk.PhotoImage(file = GUI_support.img_update)
    self.Canvas1.create_image(100, 75, image = img)
```

Comment: If `img_update` is a function, then `file = GUI_support.img_update` should be `file = GUI_support.img_update()` instead.

Comment: @acw1668 you are completely right! thanks